# Как поменять цвет кнопки vk_api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Первый раз пишу бота для ВК. С помощью модуля `vk_api` сделал клавиатуру и кнопку для него. Она функционирует, но не меняется цвет кнопки. Что я делаю не так?

### Код (не полный)##

```
#Так импортирую vk_api
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import vk_api.keyboard as v_key
# Таким образом делаю клавиатуру
key = v_key.VkKeyboard(one_time=True, inline=False)
key.add_button(label='Продолжить', color='primary')
#Сообщение и клавиатура отправляются пользователю
vk.messages.send(
                    user_id=event.obj['from_id'],
                    random_id=event.obj['random_id'],
                    keyboard=key.get_keyboard(),
                    message='ТУТ ТЕКСТ'
                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить:

```
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboardColor
```

А кнопку сделать так:

```
key.add_button('Продолжить', color=VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY)
#PRIMARY/SECONDARY/POSITIVE/NEGATIVE
```